# How to return from outer function results from inner asynchronous function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, get, async-await, es6-promise

I just had to do a coding test that involved a Node GET call, parsing the return data and returning it to the calling function so that it could be printed to stdout.  All went fine except I couldn't figure out how to get it out of the inner asynchronous function and then get the outer function to return it.  The rules of the game, as I understand them, was that I could only work on the code *within* my interior function.

The first iteration I came up with was something like this (I'm leaving out the tricky processing of the data which the original test required)

```
const https = require('https')


function inner() {
  let buff = ''


  https.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts', res => {
    res.on('data', data => {
      buff += data
    })

    res.on('end', () => {
      return JSON.parse(buff)
    })


  })


}

function outer() {
  const results = inner()
}


outer()
```

which doesn't work, because returning from the inner function `res.on('end',...)` doesn't return from the outer.

Then I thought to bend the rules of the game a bit and use `await`, which requires me to make my inner function `async`.  This works, up to a point.  But now the `async` function is returning a Promise, and I have no control over the outer function to unwrap it (it's part of the test environment).

```
 const https = require('https')

async function inner() {
  let buff = ''

  const get = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    https.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts', res => {
      res.on('data', data => {
        buff += data
      })

      res.on('end', () => {

        resolve(JSON.parse(buff))
      })


    })

  })
  try {
    const results = await get()
    return results
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e.message)
  }


}

function outer() {
  const results = inner()
}


outer()
```

I'm sure there is a stupidly obvious answer, but I'm not seeing it.  Perhaps there is a Promise-based method of `on.('end')` that eliminates these inner functions? Any help finding the *best* solution much appreciated (and yes, the test is over, I'm just doing this for my own knowledge).

Comment: @HereticMonkey -- if it's a true duplicate I'm fine with this question being closed. BUT, the tricky part about this question is that it operates within a strict environment, that is, I don't have full control over the calling function.  For example, I can't make the calling function `async`,which would solve the problem.  I had looked for other answers on SO prior to posting, but all of them assumed you had more control than I did.  I'll look (again) at the link you posted.

Comment: What does 'strict environment' mean and what is this a problem? You can't make it work like `results = inner()`, no matter what you do.

Comment: Strict environment means it was a coding test online, that is, I was supposed to code an inner function that made a Node GET request and return the JSON data to the testing platform. The only way I knew was to use the Node https methods above.  Perhaps there's an entirely better way to solve the task

Comment: Asynchronous functions by definition don't complete until after the calling function returns. It's simply not possible to return the value normally.

Comment: If the coding test is expecting that, it's either a bad test or you misunderstand.